# Convert Dictionary to Pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dict as follows:

```
data_dict = {'1.160.139.117': ['712907','742068'],
 '1.161.135.205': ['667386','742068'],
 '1.162.51.21': ['326136', '663056', '742068']}
```

I want to convert the dict into a dataframe:

```
df= pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_dict, orient='index')
```

[image]

How can I create a dataframe that has columns representing the values of the dictionary and rows representing the keys of the dictionary?, as below:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The best option is #4

```
pd.get_dummies(df.stack()).sum(level=0)
```

#### Option 1:

One way you could do it:

```
df.stack().reset_index(level=1)\
  .set_index(0,append=True)['level_1']\
  .unstack().notnull().mul(1)
```

Output:

```
               326136  663056  667386  712907  742068
1.160.139.117       0       0       0       1       1
1.161.135.205       0       0       1       0       1
1.162.51.21         1       1       0       0       1
```

#### Option 2

Or with a litte reshaping and pd.crosstab:

```
df2 = df.stack().reset_index(name='Values')
pd.crosstab(df2.level_0,df2.Values)
```

Output:

```
Values         326136  663056  667386  712907  742068
level_0                                              
1.160.139.117       0       0       0       1       1
1.161.135.205       0       0       1       0       1
1.162.51.21         1       1       0       0       1
```

#### Option 3

```
df.stack().reset_index(name="Values")\
  .pivot(index='level_0',columns='Values')['level_1']\
  .notnull().astype(int)
```

Output:

```
Values         326136  663056  667386  712907  742068
level_0                                              
1.160.139.117       0       0       0       1       1
1.161.135.205       0       0       1       0       1
1.162.51.21         1       1       0       0       1
```

#### Option 4 (@Wen pointed out a short solution and fastest so far)

```
pd.get_dummies(df.stack()).sum(level=0)
```

Output:

```
               326136  663056  667386  712907  742068
1.160.139.117       0       0       0       1       1
1.161.135.205       0       0       1       0       1
1.162.51.21         1       1       0       0       1
```

Comment: maybe `pd.get_dummies(df.stack()).sum(level=0)` :-)

Comment: Please do it, my friend  :-) and  happy thanksgiving

Comment: @wen  Happy T-day to you too!